# c++ InterlockedExchangePointer and pointer alignment

Tags: c++, pointers, alignment

The [documentation for the InterlockedExchangePointer Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683609%28VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> On a **64-bit system**, the parameters are 64 bits and the Target parameter **must be aligned on 64-bit boundaries**; otherwise, the function will behave unpredictably. On a **32-bit system**, the parameters are 32 bits and the Target parameter **must be aligned on 32-bit boundaries**.

I'm **compiling for 32bits** and the program will **run on 32bits and 64bits architectures**; does the following structure provide pointers which are **usable by InterlockedExchangePointer on any (32 or 64bits) running architecture without code adaptation**?

```
template <class T>
struct Foo {
    enum { count = 3 };
    __declspec(align(64)) T objects[count];
};
```

(I suppose that if a single pointer is aligned on 64bits it's also aligned on 32bits -- even if there is a padding if running on 32bits)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it matters though - 64-bit and 32-bit builds would generate different instructions. Running a 32-bit binary under 64-bit OS still gives you 32-bit VM.

Comment: You don't need to mess with __declspec at all. Pointers (like all other datatypes) are automatically aligned when allocated normally. This documentation note is simply to point out that it won't work if you manually mess up the alignment

Comment: jalf, Well, I messed up with allocated storage and non-pointer member object alignment; void* pointers[count] became T objects[count], so this is not allocated any more...

Answer (score 2):

On 64-bit system program that written for 32-bit platform will work through compatibility layer (WoW, Windows on Windows), and your pointers must be aligned on 32 bits.

But, if you compile your program in 64 bit mode - your pointers will be automaticaly aligned on 64 bits.

Comment: I messed up with allocated storage and non-pointer member object alignment; I edited the member type (void* array -> T); please review your answer if necessary.

Comment: @moala. In any case compiler by default (if thigs like #pragma pack not used) will align pointers on 32/64 bits boundary.